# Emulated Android device: How to get scale / pixel ratio to match physical phone with non-standard density?

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

My emulated android device has a scale value (`MediaQuery.devicePixelRatio` in flutter) that is different from the one of my physical device (Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra), so all sizes are different on the emulated device (`3.0x`) than on my physical device (`3.5x`). I have made sure that the device size and screen resolution is set correctly in the emulator. I guess the problem is that the pixel ratio of `3.5x` doesn't fall into the "official" density buckets (xxhdpi has `3.0x`, xxxhdpi has `4.0x`).

How can I change the `devicePixelRatio` in the emulator, so it correctly reflects how things will look on my real phone? And why does it deviate in the first place?

Answer (score -1):

yes, It is very much possible... you will need to change **config.ini** file in
PATH:

```
.android/avd/<device_name>.avd/config.ini
```

you have to change the following properties:

**hw.height, hw.width and hw.density**

density is dpi. so either you can change density to that of device or more stable

option is to change hw.height and hw.width, with values calculated using:

find

**DPR**: **original_ppi**/ **150 (standard ppi)**

find **viewport** = **Original Resolution**/**DPR**

**emulator_DPR** = **mention DPR(hw.density)**/**150**

now **hw.height** x **hw.widht** = **viewport** * **emulator_DPR**

Comment: You can only choose between the following DPIs:
120, 160, 213, 240, 280, 320, 360, 400, 420, 480, 560, 640